# How extract text from a tag using Nokogiri

Tags: html, regex, nokogiri, href, extract

Example:

```
<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/replies/286"rel="nofollow"target"_blank">http://localhost:3000/replies/279</a><br><p>
```

Currently using Nokogiri to grab the href from the `<a>`:

```
doc.search('a').each do |node|
  href = node.attributes['href'].try(:value)
```

I need to make sure what's in the text part is what's in the href and I'm not sure how to extract that.

Comment: node.text will give you the text content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the basics for checking:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/replies/286"rel="nofollow"target"_blank">http://localhost:3000/replies/279</a><br><p>
EOT

link = doc.at('a')
link['href'] == link.text # => false
```

Modifying the HTML so the HREF and `text` match:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/replies/279"rel="nofollow"target"_blank">http://localhost:3000/replies/279</a><br><p>
EOT

link = doc.at('a')
link['href'] == link.text # => true
```

`at` returns only the first node that matches the selector, so if you're looking to check multiple nodes you'll want to use `search` and iterate over the NodeSet it returns.